# Orientation constraints from current pose

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm are trying to use orientation constraints to keep the end effector in the same orientation as the current pose,
however I can't get it to work. It always gives the following error:

> Orientation constraint violated for link 'ee_link'.

How is this possible? Because I set the constraint orientation from the current pose, and it already errors in the current pose.

I'm setting the orientation constraint as follows:

```
this->ocm.link_name = "ee_link";
this->ocm.header.frame_id = "base_link"
this->ocm.weight = 1.0;

this->ocm.orientation = this->move_group.getCurrentPose().pose.orientation;
this->ocm.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = 0.1;
this->ocm.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = 0.1;
this->ocm.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = 2.0 * 3.14;

this->constraints.orientation_constraints.push_back(this->ocm);
this->move_group.setPathConstraints(this->constraints);
```

Our goal is to keep the end effector up, so it won't drop the object (a plant) the end effector is holding.
I want to restrict the orientation, so it may only use yaw to rotate in it's path.

Maybe something is wrong with our tf tree?:

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272759/orientation-constraints-from-current-pose/) by [jeffreyp23](https://answers.ros.org/users/32209/jeffreyp23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
this->ocm.link_name = "ee_link";
this->ocm.header.frame_id = "base_link";
this->ocm.orientation = this->move_group.getCurrentPose().pose.orientation;
```

Are you sure `getCurrentPose` returns the pose in "base_link" and your current end-effector is "ee_link"?
Try always to keep frame_ids and coordinates together and if you specify a hard-coded link name in one place, do the same for the rest of the code:

```
auto current_pose= this->move_group.getCurrentPose(this->ocm.link_name);
this->ocm.header.frame_id = current_pose.header.frame_id;
this->ocm.orientation = current_pose.pose.orientation;
```

It's hard to debug this further without more information on how you trigger the error.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1